Show that $ \frac{1}{|h|}\int_a^b |f(x+h)-f(x)|dx\le M $
Let $f\in BV[a,b]$ (bounded variation). Show that there is a constant $M>0$ and $\delta>0$ so that $0<|h|<\delta$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{|h|}\int_a^b |f(x+h)-f(x)|dx\le M
$$

Define $V_{[a,b]}(f)$ is the supreme of $\sum_{i=1}^n|f(x_j)-f(x_{j+1})|$ for all partition $a\le x_1\le\dots\le x_{n+1}\le b$.
In the proof, I am confused about one step:
$$
\frac{1}{|h|}\int_{a+h}^b V_{[a,u]}(f)du-\frac{1}{|h|}\int_a^{b-h}V_{[a,x]}(f)dx=\frac{1}{|h|}\int_{b-h}^b V_{[a,x]}(f)dx-\frac{1}{|h|}\int_a^{a+h}V_{[a,x]}(f)dx
$$
How do we get this step?

$$
\begin{align}&\int_{a+h}^b V_{[a,u]}(f)du+\int_a^{a+h}V_{[a,x]}(f)dx\\&=\int_a^b V_{[a,x]}(f)dx\\&=\int_{b-h}^b V_{[a,x]}(f)dx+\int_a^{b-h}V_{[a,x]}(f)dx.\end{align}
$$

How to get the second term in the first line?

By moving it from the original right hand side
